# Random Error with in_array

Tags: php, c++, arrays

So, i was challenged by a coworker to build a random poker hand generator. At the time, all I had was my phone that I could run php with.
So, after some tinkering and lots of searching, i came up with this:

```
<?php
   $cards;
   $card = array();
   function GetCard($getSuit, $getNumber){
    for($s=0; $s < 4; $s++){
          for($n=0; $n < 13; $n++){

                if($s == 0){
        //Clubs
                    $suits[$s] = "-C";
                } else if($s == 1){
        //Hearts
                    $suits[$s] = "-H";
                } else if($s == 2){
        //Spades
                    $suits[$s] = "-S";
                } else if($s == 3){
        //Diamonds
                    $suits[$s] = "-D";
                }
                if($n == 0){
                  $num[$n] = "A";
                } else if($n == 10){
                  $num[$n] = "J";
                } else if($n == 11){
                  $num[$n] = "Q";
                } else if($n == 12){
                  $num[$n] = "K";
                } else {
                  $num[$n] = $n+1;
                }
                $cards[$s][$n] = $num[$n].$suits[$s];
          }
        }
        return $cards[$getSuit][$getNumber];
    }
    function GetRandomPokerHand(){
        $i = 0;
        while($i < 5){ 
                mt_srand();
        $rs = mt_rand(0,3);
        $rn = mt_rand(0,12);
        $randomCard = GetCard($rs,$rn);
        if(!in_array($randomCard,$card)){
            $card[i] = GetCard($rs,$rn);
            echo $card[i];
            echo " ";
            $i++;
        }else{
            echo " found ";
        }
    }
   }
        GetRandomPokerHand();
?>
```

I get the hand, however... every so often in_array fails and I get the same card twice. i added the "else" statement with "found" to see if it was finding the duplicate at all. It did and echos "found", and occasionally it STILL displays a duplicate.

So I decided to try the same code (well roughly the same) when i got home with c++: (Using "switch" instead of "if" was because of preference and switch statements are too much trouble on a phone)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;
string suits[4];
string num[13];
string cards[4][13];

string GetCard(int getSuit, int getNumber){
    for (int s = 0; s < 4; s++){
        for (int n = 0; n < 13; n++){
            switch (s){
                case 0:
                    suits[s] = "-C";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    suits[s] = "-H";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    suits[s] = "-S";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    suits[s] = "-D";
                    break;
            }
            switch (n){
                case 0:
                    num[n] = "A";
                    break;
                case 10:
                    num[n] = "J";
                    break;
                case 11:
                    num[n] = "Q";
                    break;
                case 12: 
                    num[n] = "K";
                    break;
                default:
                    num[n] = to_string(n + 1);
                    break;
            }
            cards[s][n] = num[n] + suits[s];
        }
    }
    string card = { cards[getSuit][getNumber] };
    return card;
}

bool in_array(const string &value, const vector<string> &array){
    return find(array.begin(), array.end(), value) != array.end();
}

void GetRanddomPokerHand(){
    int hand = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    while (hand < 5){
        int suit = rand() % 4;
        int value = rand() % 13;
        string randomCard = GetCard(suit, value);
        vector<string> card = { "", "", "", "", "" };
        if (!in_array(randomCard, card)){
            card[hand] = randomCard;
            cout << card[hand] << endl;
            hand++;
        }else{
            cout << "found";
        }
    }
}


int main(){
    GetRanddomPokerHand();

    char stop;
    cin >> stop; // yes, i know this isn't necessary in VE2013
    return 0;
}
```

Same problem. I can't seem to figure out why the duplicates are being printed in either case.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In the c++ one you have this line inside your loop

```
vector<string> card = { "", "", "", "", "" };
```

That is creating a fresh blank hand each time, so it never will have duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

$card[i] need to be $card[$i]

your $card array always has only 1 element which is last card cause of that mistake ;)

Comment: ACK! This is why you shouldn't program with a mini-mini keyboard (cell phone). Thanks, that fixed it